# datetime format global change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Rather than using something like this for datatime values:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.DOB))
```

Is it possible to set the format globally (e.g. in the web.config) in asp.net mvc 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a DisplayTemplate at `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.cshtml`

```
@model DateTime

@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model))
```

Whenever you use `@Html.DisplayFor()` with a `DateTime` property, MVC will use this template.

Comment: Thanks excellent. Given your code I have implemented it slightly different: @String.Format("{0}", Model != null ? ((DateTime)Model).ToString("R") : "n/a") Do you think it is possible to pass in the parameter "R" (i.e. time format)? Btw, is DisplayTemplate a mvc 3 concept? Never heard of it ...

Comment: I think they were introduced in MVC 2. See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html for an overview.